# Datomic invalid connection config

Tags: clojure, datomic

I tried the following code to create a datomic database and connect to it:

```
(let [cfg (-> env :datomic-cfg)
               client (d/client cfg)]
           (do
             (d/create-database
              client
              {:db-name "humboi-march-2021"})
             (d/connect client {:db-name "humboi-march-2021"})))
```

However, I’m getting the following error:

```
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at datomic.client.impl.pro/create-spi (pro.clj:72).
Invalid connection config: {:server-type :peer-server, :access-key "key-0680cb34675d5fd59", :secret "<ELIDED>", :endpoint "http://entry.humboi-2021.us-east-1.datomic.net:8182", :validate-hostnames false}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your uri has to be a string, for example I use:

```
(let [uri "datomic:free://localhost:4334/name"]
  (d/create-database uri)
  (d/connect uri))
```